# Could not find fuction %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

My code looks like this:

```
brfss2013<-brfss2013 %>%
  mutate (bpyes=(bphigh4="yes"))
```

the chunk runs, but it won't knit.  I have removed "dplyr" and replaced it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you loaded dplyr or tidyverse in the markdown document? Also, `bpyes=(bphigh4="yes")` should probably be `bpyes = bphigh4 == "yes"`

Comment: Thank you for your response Richard Telford.  Yes, I loaded dplyr and corrected  bpyes = bphigh4 == "yes", and I still get the same error.  I wonder if there is a bug?

Comment: As it stands, this question is unanswerable as we cannot reproduce the problem from that snippet of code. At a minimum, show the chunk where you load the packages

Comment: >library(dplyr)
> library(ggplot2)
> load("brfss2013.RData")

Comment: I am very new at this as you can probably can tell.  Thank you again.

Comment: you have a space between mutate and the open parenthesis.